# How to return actions and parameters in OPTIONS request with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, metadata, django-countries

I try to return a list of select options for countries using django-countries and django rest framework. I use JWT_AUTH for the authentication.

When I try a options request:

```
curl \
  -H "Authentication: JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFsYmVydG9fdmVudGEiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJlbWFpbCI6IiIsImV4cCI6MTUwODE2Mzg4Mn0.svxqTThCahSl1Vu27sMjuJyd1PRLk28-Xgn2OKKb5-g"\
  -X OPTIONS \
  -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/core/perfilViajeroUserPass/
```

The response is:

```
{
 "name":"Perfil Viajero User Pass Create",
 "description":"",
 "renders":["application/json","text/html"],
 "parses":[
           "application/json",
           "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           "multipart/form-data"
          ]
}
```

But I think that it should be something like this by default:

```
{
"name": "To Do List",
"description": "List existing 'To Do' items, or create a new item.",
"renders": [
    "application/json",
    "text/html"
],
"parses": [
    "application/json",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "multipart/form-data"
],
"actions": {
    "POST": {
        "note": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": false,
            "label": "title",
            "max_length": 100
        }
    }
}
```

}

Someone could help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

I change my view class type from `APIView` to `generics.CreateAPIView` and know it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Adding another answer since I recently ran into the same issue and found it a bit mystifying -- when making an `OPTIONS` request, Django Rest Framework uses the view's `Metadata` class to construct a response. The default `Metadata` class is `SimpleMetadata`, as mentioned [in the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/#setting-the-metadata-scheme). **However**, `SimpleMetadata` only adds the `actions` key to the response body if the view in question defines the method `get_serializer()`. I'm not sure why this is the case, but see [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/metadata.py#L67-L70) for the relevant code.

`rest_framework.generics.GenericAPIView` [defines a `get_serializer()` method](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/generics.py#L103-L110), so (authenticated) `OPTIONS` requests made to these views will return a response body with the `actions` key. But `rest_framework.views.APIView` does not define this method, so the `actions` key will always be absent.

If you have to use `rest_framework.views.APIView`, you could work around this by defining a `get_serializer()` method on your APIView class. Which feels a little hacky, but I tested it and it works:

```py
class MyView(views.APIView):
    def get_serializer(self):
        return MySerializer()

    def post(self):
        ...
```

Comment: I believe it's because `APIView` has no `serializer_class` attribute out of the box either, although you can add one if you want to enable browsable API forms for `APIView` views. It could also be because the method in `SimpleMetadata` needs access to the view's serializer, and because there's no `serializer_class` attribute nor a method `get_serializer` implemented, there's no easy way to determine this from the separate class. That portion could definitely use a rewrite though imo. It's a small but important issue that's hard to catch unless you're looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change some of the content:

- `name` is the view's `get_view_name` which is the view's name slightly reworked.
- `description` is the view's `get_view_description` which reworks the view's docstring.

Otherwise if you want something more complex, you'll probably want to customize the view's metadata as explained in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/#custom-metadata-classes

Comment: but the documentation says that actions are included by default:

'Here's an example response that demonstrates the information that is returned by default.'

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/

Comment: Then either there's something wrong in your view, either you don't have the required permission to perform the action.

Comment: I have added permission_classes = (AllowAny,) to my view so I dont know where the error is

Answer (score 0):

Another reason an OPTIONS response doesn't contain the `actions` list is if the view doesn't allow the PUT or POST methods.

See `SimpleMetadata.determine_actions()` in the DRF source `rest_framework/metadata.py`.